# maven 3 dependency jar in repository

Tags: maven

I have a maven 3 repository. There are some external jars that I need to add as dependencies in POM. I created the folder structure of the jar manually in he repository and pasted the jar downloaded from internet. Still there is an error in POM stating the dependent jar file is not present. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Please add some code illustrating the problem you are trying to solve. Also the literal error message may help.

Comment: Why downloading the jars manually and not importing it from the maven central repository?

Comment: Best is to start using a repository manager and install those files there and from that you can use them as usual dependencies.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Actually, the jar in not present at MAVEN repo I am using. Thus I want to download it from internet and upload at my local repo. Is my approach right? If not what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Creating the folder structure manually will not work. If you have some jars that you want to use as dependencies in maven you should install them in your local repository:

The command you must use is this:

```
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

For example:

```
 mvn install:install-file -Dfile=myLibrary.jar -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myLibrary -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

More info at: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Actually, the jar in not present at MAVEN repo I am using. Thus I want to download it from internet and upload at my local repo. Is my approach right? If not what should I do?

Comment: I know that you jar is not in your maven repo. I told you how to add your jar in your lcoal repository. First download the jar (example:myLibrary.jar) from internet, after that run the command I told you, so your new jar is added in your local repo.